# iOS7 Story Board in Xcode 5 not showing images

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uistoryboard

I am working on a project having two story boards, one for 3.5inch screens and one for 4 inch screens. The problem is  the image view in my 4inch storyboard (iphone5) is showing a big white question mark despite the fact the image is in the project and selected correctly through attributes inspector. The images in 3.5 inch storyboard are being hooked up correctly and being shown in interface builder. Some point are here regarding the problem:

1. Image views are showing question mark only in Interface Builder, when i run it it shows up there.
2. Problem only with 4 inch storyboard (for iphone 5)
3. Naming conventions are:
   3.1. For 3.5 Inch Screen : bg_home.png & bg_home@2x.png
   3.2. For 4.0 Inch Screen : bg_home-568h.png & bg_home-568@2x.png

Solutions tried already:

1. removed images references and added again
2. deleted images and added again
3. Cleaned the project and re-built it
4. Most important point and wired one that when i convert the image name to bg_home_568h.png and bg_home_568h@2x.png, and add them in the project, the problem is solved and images show right away in the storybaord.

Any solution from you people will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the images in the target build phases under "Copy files" ? And in storyboard, you need to reference the image as "bg_home_568h.png", do you use the @2x ?

Comment: I don't think i have to add it manually there. But to double check, these images are already there. And yes i do have @2x images also. Is it wrong naming convention? But i have seen many people using this convention, and it works there. But not working in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by:

1. Removing images from the project
2. Renaming it with the format "bg_home_568h@2x.png" from the old format "bg_home-568h@2x.png"
3. Adding renamed back to the project again
4. And hooked up all the imageViews again to renamed image files

Working Now! Seemed to be naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added resources first
if you are assigning image name with @2x in end then don't write @2x i-e you have two images with names example.png , example@2x.png. Then just write example.png their in attribute inspector.

Comment: I am already doing the same. I know that "@2x" is for ratina images that ios picks up by self, we dont have to specify it, we have to write just without "@2x".